# Delete/Drop columns with name beginning with X*

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data and framework:

```
raw = { 'A': [1, 10],'B': [100,1000],'logA': [0, 1], 'logB':[2,3]}
df= pd.DataFrame(raw, columns=['A','B','logA','logB'])
```

How can I drop all columns that starts with "log"? I have tried `df.drop(['logA','logB'],axis=1)`, but I want to know if there is something I can do with `df.columns.str.startswith('log')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

**Option 1**
use `loc` and boolean indexing

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('log')]

    A     B
0   1   100
1  10  1000
```

---

**Option 2**
Use `pd.DataFrame.filter` with a negative lookahead regex

```
df.filter(regex='^(?!log)')

    A     B
0   1   100
1  10  1000
```